# How do different browsers handle multiple selected options

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

How do different browsers handle multiple selected options in a situation like the one below, where a programmer erroneously or unknowingly selects multiple default options in their HTML:

```
   <select>
        <option selected="selected"> Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
        <option selected="selected">Option 4</option>
        <option>Option 5</option>
        <option>Option 6</option>
    </select>
```

At the moment I have access to chrome, firefox, opera and safari, and they all seem to unanimously select `option 4`, probably because the browser loads from top to bottom. Nevertheless, better be safe than sorry. In the browser we all love to hate i.e IE (no pun intended), or Microsoft edge, are they any different?

Comment: What do you mean by "where a user erroneously or unknowingly selects multiple default options in their HTML" - what are you making that would allow a user to achieve this? Can you not apply validation on your end to alert the user that they've made a mistake?

Comment: Also the specification [dictates](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-option-selected): "A select element whose multiple attribute is not specified **must not have more than one descendant option element with its selected attribute set**". It's entirely down to the browser vendor to implement how this is handled (meaning this could realistically change without warning between versions of the same browser, let alone different browsers).

Comment: I'll clarify that in a sec. My question is not about a website user, but rather a user of the HTML language :-)

Comment: `user of the HTML language` - or "author"?

Comment: @JaromandaX According to the question a "programmer".

Comment: or that, though pure HTML is "authored" not "programmed" (in my opinion)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - "It's entirely down to the browser vendor to implement how this is handled". No it's not. How to handle the case is specified in the HTML5 spec at http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#ask-for-a-reset, which says as the options are added to the DOM, the last selected option in tree order will be kept as the selected one and any others will be deselected, exactly matching the behaviour identified in the question.

Comment: @Alohci I believe that only applies if a list of options with one `selected` option already exists and a new `selected` option is being added. In OP's case both `selected` options are being added at the same time, thus why it mentions that select elements must not have more than one descendant option with the `selected` attribute set. At least, that's what I understand from "If nodes are inserted or nodes are removed causing the list of options to gain or lose one or more option elements, or if an option element in the list of options asks for a reset...".

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I think what Alohci meant to make know in the specs is that: "If two or more option elements in the select element’s list of options have their selectedness set to true
Set the selectedness of all but the last option element with its selectedness set to true in the list of options in tree order to false."

Comment: Yes, that part is prefixed by the sentence I quoted. I don't think it's relevant when a select list is first loaded, but rather when an existing select list is modified.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - No, they don't get inserted at the same time. The parser algorithm will insert each option element into the DOM as it encounters it, so the "if nodes are inserted ..." applies at each parser insert. To see that happening, see https://jsfiddle.net/kt0u7305/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Browserling](https://www.browserling.com/browse/win/vista/ie/9/https%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2F26x7osbt%2F), it shows the same results in IE 9, and I also tested it on my PC. Microsoft Edge also shows the same results. I think that every browser interprets this on it's own way. According to the W3 specification:

> A select element whose multiple attribute is not specified must not have more than one descendant option element with its selected attribute set.

If you want to go in more detail on this, put the code you provided on a JSFiddle and try the link in [Browserling](https://www.browserling.com) or [Browsershots](http://browsershots.org/).